# Azure Search - Smaller Facet Counts Not Returning From Index

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure Search indexing for creating a faceted search of products. I have around 5 facets to aid in filtering the list of displayed products.

One thing I have noticed is that if there are quite a lot of products listed for filtering down using facets, smaller search items that belong within a facet do not get returned from the index.

For example (in its simplicity), if my index had the following cars manufacturers listed within a facet:

- Audi (312)
- BMW (203)
- Volvo (198)
- Skoda (4)

I would find that Skoda would not get returned, since there is such a small amount of search results linked to that manufacturer.

I can see this is the case when I search the index directly within the Azure Portal by using this query: `facet=<facet-field-name>`

After some research I came across the following [explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-faceted-navigation):

> Facet counts can be inaccurate due to the sharding architecture. Every search index has multiple shards, and each shard reports the top N facets by document count, which is then combined into a single result. If some shards have many matching values, while others have fewer, you may find that some facet values are missing or under-counted in the results.
>
> Although this behavior could change at any time, if you encounter this behavior today, you can work around it by artificially inflating the count: to a large number to enforce full reporting from each shard. If the value of count: is greater than or equal to the number of unique values in the field, you are guaranteed accurate results. However, when document counts are high, there is a performance penalty, so use this option judiciously.

Based on the above quote, how do I *artificially inflate the count* to get around this issue? Or does anyone know a better approach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default facet count is 10. You can specify a larger count using the `count` parameter as part of the facet expression. For example, assuming you're using the REST API with an HTTP GET request:

```
facet=myfield,count:100
```

If you're using the .NET SDK:

```
var parameters =
    new SearchParameters()
    {
        Facets = new[] { "myfield,count:100" }
    };

var results = indexClient.Documents.Search("*", parameters);
```

You can find more details about the facet expression syntax in the [Azure Search REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents).

Comment: Great! But how do I stipulate the count via the API - IndexClient.Documents.Search<T>()? I've checked the SearchParameters properties and can't see where I can update that facet count.

Comment: It's part of the facet expression itself. Just add it to the `SearchParameters.Facets` property. I'll edit my answer to include an example.

Comment: @BruceJohnston can we get all the facets available, what value should i pass for count in that case?

Comment: @GaneshKarewad Please ask this as a separate question so that others will be able to find the answer easily.

Comment: SearchParameters sp = new SearchParameters()
                {
                    SearchMode = SearchMode.Any,
                    Facets = new List<String>() { "state,count:60,sort:count"} }; We can add sorting logic as well into this.